# What to change in circular barplot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, project

I am trying to present some data

```
emertim=c("M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019")

group=c(rep("Bujqesi,Silvkulture dhe peshkim",6), rep("Industria",6), rep("Ndertimi",6), rep("Tregtia",6), rep("Informacioni dhe komunikimi",6), rep("Sigurimi",6), rep("Aktivitete legjislative dhe shkencore", 6), rep("Administrata publike dhe shendetesia",6), rep("Arte",6), rep(“Gjithsej”,6))

paga=c(37.163,34.305,37.529,35.486,37.753,35.069,49.301,31.916,51.541,33.454,53.759,35.172,44.057,37.903,44.457,39.737,42.284,41.997,36.044,32.224,38.303,34.330,40.651,36.495,78.427,66.893,81.683,68.162,85.468,73.232,116.081,95.406,121.384,96.997,118.629,100.775,57.191,53.961,60.625,56.816,61.143,56.992,64.869,55.969,66.108,57.149,68.404,59.081,47.647,52.078,49.608,54.202,59.760,55.653,51.392,46.018,53.181,47.490,54.940,49.411)
data=data.frame(emertim, group, paga)
```

Whatever I do, I get an error message
"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data"

This is the code I have(too much code to be put in the question):

https://notepad.ltd/x1v8ff7l

I can't seem to find the error.

Comment: I think you can avoid the code error when you make a minimum reproducible example. Try to remove as much lines of code as possible so that you can still reproduce the error. For example, you probably only need one `geom_segment` if that's where the error comes from.

Comment: I just tried it and I got the same message. I also looked at a website https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/297-circular-barplot-with-groups.html  and tired to adapt it by the example but still no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider cleaning up your code of syntax issues and heed the error message that indicates the problematic issue (emphasis added):

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (10): **hjust**

Also, use `lapply` or `for` to avoid the repetitive `geom_segment` lines. Finally, consider saving `angle` and `hjust` aesthetics in `base_data` and abbreviate the group names to better render on plot

**Data**

```r
emertim <- c("M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018",
             "F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019",
             "M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018",
             "F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019",
             "M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018",
             "F2018","M2019","F2019","M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019",
             "M2017","F2017","M2018","F2018","M2019","F2019")

group <- c(rep("Bujqesi, Silvkulture dhe peshkim",6), 
           rep("Industria",6), rep("Ndertimi",6), 
           rep("Tregtia",6), rep("Informacioni dhe komunikimi",6), 
           rep("Sigurimi",6), rep("Aktivitete legjislative dhe shkencore", 6), 
           rep("Administrata publike dhe shendetesia",6), rep("Arte",6), 
           rep("Gjithsej",6))

paga <- c(37.163,34.305,37.529,35.486,37.753,35.069,49.301,31.916,51.541,
          33.454,53.759,35.172,44.057,37.903,44.457,39.737,42.284,41.997,
          36.044,32.224,38.303,34.330,40.651,36.495,78.427,66.893,81.683,
          68.162,85.468,73.232,116.081,95.406,121.384,96.997,118.629,100.775,
          57.191,53.961,60.625,56.816,61.143,56.992,64.869,55.969,
          66.108,57.149,68.404,59.081,47.647,52.078,49.608,54.202,59.760,
          55.653,51.392,46.018,53.181,47.490,54.940,49.411)

data <- data.frame(emertim, group, paga)
```

**Graph Data**

**Note**: Starting in R 4.0, `data.frame` defaults with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. So all string above are `character` columns and not `factor`. Therefore, `factor()` below is used at `nlevels` and `levels` calls.

```r
empty_bar <- 3
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(factor(data$group)), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(factor(data$group)), each=empty_bar)
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% arrange(group)
data$id <- seq(1, nrow(data))

label_data <- data
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) / number_of_bar    
label_data$hjust <- ifelse(angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

base_data <- data %>%
  # ABBREVIATE GROUP NAME
  mutate(group = paste0(sapply(strsplit(group, " "), `[`, 1), "...")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

base_data <- base_data %>%
  # ADD ANGLE AND HJUST COLUMNS
  transform(angle = 90 - 360 * (seq(1, nrow(base_data))-0.5) / nrow(base_data)) %>%
  mutate(angle = ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle),
         hjust = c(rep(1, 5), rep(0, 5)))

grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]
```

**Plot**

```r
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=paga, fill=group)) +       
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=paga, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  lapply(seq(90, 0, by=-10), function(i)
    geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = i, xend = start, yend = i), 
                 colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE)) +
  annotate("text", x=rep(max(data$id),4), y = c(20, 40, 60, 80),
           label = c("20", "40", "60", "80") , color="grey", size=3 , 
           angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
  ylim(-100,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, 
            aes(x=id, y=paga+10, label=emertim, hjust=hjust), 
            color="black", fontface="bold", alpha=0.6, size=2.5,
            angle=label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  
  geom_segment(data=base_data, 
               aes(x=start, y=-5, xend=end, yend=-5), 
               colour="black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6, inherit.aes=FALSE) +
  
  geom_text(data=base_data, 
            aes(x=title, y=-18, label=group),
            hjust=base_data$hjust, colour="black", alpha=0.8, size=4,
            angle=base_data$angle, fontface="bold", inherit.aes=FALSE)

ggsave("myGroupCircularBarChart.png", plot=p, device="png")
```

[image: Plot Output]